# Cannot connect to localhost with cURL on Command Prompt

Tags: curl, intellij-idea, command-line, localhost, command-prompt

I've just installed **cURL** on my hard-drive in order to use for testing with my localhost (on the command prompt). However I cannot connect to any port. You can see the directory and my input below:

> C:\Users\me\curl\src>curl -v http://localhost:9000

which gives me:

> - Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:9000/
> - timeout on name lookup is not supported
> - Trying ::1...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - Trying 127.0.0.1...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - connect to ::1 port 9000 failed: Connection refused
> - connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9000 failed: Connection refused
> - Failed to connect to localhost port 9000: Connection refused
> - Closing connection 0 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000: Connection refused

Perhaps I should have added that  I am using IntelliJ and have since enabled cURL on the harddrive (allowing me to access it from any directory); prompting me to try the following:

> C:\Users\me\scala\play\my-project>curl -v http://localhost:9000/

which returns:

> - timeout on name lookup is not supported
> - Trying ::1...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - connect to ::1 port 9000 failed: Connection refused
> - Trying 127.0.0.1...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9000 failed: Connection refused
> - Failed to connect to localhost port 9000: Connection refused
> - Closing connection 0 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000: Connection refused

So it seems that port 9000 is not open. And I am now thinking that this needs to be configured within intelliJ - [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-a-local-server-configuration.html) - but this looks as though it is only supported on the Ultimate Edition. This might be the cause of the issue that I am having. It may be helpful to others but it would be good to be sure of this if anyone does have any more information.

Comment: Is there  anyone listen on this port

Comment: I'm doing some scala programming in IntelliJ and I thought that this was how to listen/connect to the port. Do I have this wrong?

Comment: The issue is that there is no one listening on port 9000. You need to open a socket from another program (your server) and start listening there. Otherwise your machine tries to connect to its own 9000th port, however since nobody says "I am listening" it says "Connection refused".

Comment: @htkibar thanks. I'm not entirely sure where to do that ("open a socket from another program (your server) and start listening there"). I thought that creating a virtual server on the router as outlined [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Open-Ports) would then allow me to connect to the port but unfortunately not.

Comment: Think of it like this, you have opened the port (road is open) however there is no one behind it. You need an application running there to respond to you.

Comment: @htkibar - ok - what application would you suggest? I thought that this could be done in IntelliJ (IDE) but as mentioned possibly it can only be done in the Ultimate Edition.

Comment: It is not about an IDE per se. Your code needs to open a socket and listen to it. I am adding an example code please test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your application is not started yet (so it isn't actually listening on port 9000)

You should add a run configuration in IntelliJ (`Run` > `Edit Configurations` > `+` > `Play 2 App`) and run it before doing your curl call.

Another way to start your application is just to open a terminal in your project folder, and run `sbt run`.

Comment: The simplest solutions are the best ones. I actually thought that IntelliJ would be listening to the (pre-designated) port when running but that's not so. For me this was done from the IntelliJ Terminal as you mention. Thanks for that :}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following server code while running `curl`:

```
import java.net._
import java.io._
import scala.io._

val server = new ServerSocket(9000)
while (true) {
    val serv = server.accept()

    val in = new BufferedSource(serv.getInputStream()).getLines()
    val out = new PrintStream(serv.getOutputStream())

    out.println(in.next())
    out.flush()
    serv.close()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure where you are suggesting to put that. Run it in IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes you should run in Intellij

Comment: So I ran this and something changed but when entering `curl -n http://localhost:9000/` on _Command Prompt_ I am getting back **GET / HTTP/1.1** rather than the page markup. Seems close though..

Comment: It means you are getting something back. Now you need to write to the Output stream whatever you would like to transmit.

Comment: He doesn't dp that on [the vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4b1XLka0UIw) I mentioned. I clearly don't have any idea how to do that or what exactly I am doing here. Could you suggest any references for doing this? thanks

Comment: I haven't used Play framework much, so I cannot say anything. In essence framework should be abstracting these tasks for you (writing to OutputStream under the hood). What I have shown you just proves that the issue is not about intellij nor curl.

Comment: Yes - it seems strange that anything would have to be manually configured. To be clearer: if I run the _SBT_ file in my project then I am able to output my work into a web browser but this doesn't enable me to do quick testing using _cURL_ in the _Command Prompt_ which is necessary to avoid buffering, i.e. curl -n. I can see that [_Play_ is built on top of _Netty_](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsNetty) but this still isn't providing me with the definitive answer to this. Someone else must have experienced this frustration before. With thanks