# Output two futures when they complete in Play 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, future, akka-stream

I'm humbly coming back to the community as I'm obviously in way too deep right now.

So I am trying to return two futures (in Play 2.5.2 in Scala) to screen as modules that appear onscreen when they complete. I've tried quite a few ways of trying to do this. Firstly to note that I have seemingly been able to successfully stream two *Sources* that have a reoccurring schedule:

```
  def streamAction = Action { request =>

    val source1: Source[String, NotUsed] = unfoldAsync(NotUsed) { _ ⇒
      sc.makeServiceCall("stream1").map(x ⇒ Some(NotUsed → x))
    }

    val source2: Source[String, NotUsed] = unfoldAsync(NotUsed) { _ ⇒
      sc.makeServiceCall("stream2").map(x ⇒ Some(NotUsed → x))
    }

    Ok.chunked(source1.merge(source2))
  }
```

Where `sc.makeServiceCall` refers to:

```
   class ServiceClient @Inject() (ws: WSClient) {

     def makeServiceCall(serviceName: String): Future[String] = {
       ws.url(s"http://localhost:9000/mock/$serviceName").get().map(_.body)
     }

   }
```

Which is calling:

```
   class Mock @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {

     def mock(serviceName: String) = Action.async { request =>
       serviceName match {
         case "async1" => respond("asy1", 0.second)
         case "async2" => respond("asy2", 3.second)
         case "async3" => respond("asy3", 5.second)
         case "stream1" => schedule("first", 500.millisecond)
         case "stream2" => schedule("second", 2000.millisecond)
       }
     }

     private def schedule(data: String, delay: FiniteDuration): Future[Result] = {
       akka.pattern.after(delay, actorSystem.scheduler){Future.successful(Ok(data))}
     }

     private def respond(data: String, delay: FiniteDuration): Future[Result] = {
       val promise: Promise[Result] = Promise[Result]()
       actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(delay) { promise.success(Ok(data)) }
       promise.future
     }

   }
```

So this works (as mentioned) outputting a stream like this:

> firstfirstfirstsecondfirstfirstfirstfirstsecondfirstfirstfirstfirstsecond

But in trying to output two futures when they complete (just once each) I cannot. I tried this:

```
 def outputAction = Action { request =>

   val source1: Source[String, NotUsed] = Source.fromFuture(sc.makeServiceCall("async1"))
   val source2: Source[String, NotUsed] = Source.fromFuture(sc.makeServiceCall("async2"))

   Ok.chunked(source1.merge(source2))
 }
```

This just outputs all at once (when the 2nd future completes)

> asys1asys2

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you using to call the action? There might be some buffer on the client side. Using curl, you can avoid it using the `-N` option.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet - yes the buffer might be an issue but I am also having trouble with cURL as [you'll see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326251/cannot-connect-to-localhost-with-curl-on-command-prompt) so I cannot know for sure. Is this how you would do it or have done it before?

Comment: I had some buffering issues for streaming with `Play` and cURL, resolved by -N. They were not related to merged streams however (it was in Play-2.3.8, where streams sued `Iteratee` rather than akka-streams).

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet As I say I am having issues with cURL (in the command prompt) which is returning **GET / HTTP/1.1** rather than any results and no one has been able to help me as to why. I would love to test if this is a buffering issue. I'm using Play 2.5.2

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, this seems to be a cache problem on your client side:

I used the following code and called `curl -N localhost:9000/stream`

```
def streamAction = Action { request =>

  val source1: Source[String, NotUsed] = Source.single("async1")

  val source2: Source[String, NotUsed] = Source.single("async2").initialDelay(3.seconds)

  val merged: Source[String, NotUsed] = source1.merge(source2)

  Ok.chunked(merged)
}
```

This returned `async1` and 3 seconds later `async2`, as expected.

Comment: Thanks but that only renders (both results together) at 3.03 seconds - so shortly after the longer future completes (**source2**). But I'm not able to test with cURL as mentioned because I am having those issues

Comment: Yes, but my tests shows that you have a buffer problem in your client, not a streaming problem in Play.

Comment: I'd would dearly love to see that for myself but as I say I am having issues with the ports as you will see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326251/cannot-connect-to-localhost-with-curl-on-command-prompt). I don't want to stray too far from the original question but as it is relevant - can I ask how you configured _cURL_ with _Play_?

Comment: Let's continue this conversation here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145987/output-two-futures-when-they-complete-in-play-2-5